# Dynamically Access Class Module In Ruby

Tags: ruby

My base class is `Premade` which has two subclasses: `PremadeController` and `PremadeControllerSession`. They are very similar. For example. They both need to build records in MySQl in batches of 1000, but I want `PremadeControllers` to get built before so I have them going to different queues in Resque.

So the two sub classes look like this:

```
class PremadeController < Premade

  def self.maintain
    ((max_premade_count - premade_count)/batch_size).times do
      Resque.enqueue(Workers::BuildPremadeControllerJob)
    end
  end

end
```

And:

```
class PremadeSessionController < Premade

  def self.maintain
    ((max_premade_count - premade_count)/batch_size).times do
      Resque.enqueue(Workers::BuildPremadeControllerSessionJob)
    end
  end

end
```

The only difference between those methods is the worker class (i.e. `BuildPremadeControllerSessionJob` and `BuildPremadeControllerJob`)

I've tried to put this in the parent and dynamically defining the constant, but it does not work probably due to a scope issue. For example:

```
class Premade

  def self.maintain
    ((max_premade_count - premade_count)/batch_size).times do
      Resque.enqueue(Workers::)
    end
  end

end
```

What I want to do is define this method in the parent, such as:

```
def self.maintain
  ((max_premade_count - premade_count)/batch_size).times do
    Resque.enqueue(Workers::build_job_class)
  end
end
```

Where `build_job_class` is defined in each subclass.

Please don't tell me to change Resque's worker syntax because that is not the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get) -

```
klass = Workers.const_get "Build#{self.name}Job"
```

Comment: This app is on 1.8.7. Looks like that is 1.9.3 only. Is that correct?

Comment: `const_get` is [available on 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-const_get)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to defined a `build_job_class` class method on your 2 classes that returns the appropriate worker class, i.e. `PremadeSessionController` would look like

```
class PremadeSessionController
  def self.build_job_class
    Workers::BuildPremadeControllerSessionJob
  end
end
```

Then change your maintain method to

```
def self.maintain
  ((max_premade_count - premade_count)/batch_size).times do
    Resque.enqueue(build_job_class)
  end
end
```